# What to do with the [tag:octave] questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

There are about 19 questions using the [octave](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/octave) tag which is a legitimate GNU math based program similar to MATLAB.  However, a majority of the questions that I've encountered have been language specific rather than program specific:

- https://superuser.com/questions/320155/plotting-from-m-file-with-octave-for-windows-does-not-show-plot
- https://superuser.com/questions/412381/get-an-yerror-plot-without-a-line-in-octave
- [Octave: Precise value in Decimal or Continuous Fraction for 729 / 4^3](https://superuser.com/questions/51431/octave-precise-value-in-decimal-or-continuous-fraction-for-729-43)
- [GNU Octave: How to change base from DEC to BIN?](https://superuser.com/questions/51414/gnu-octave-how-to-change-base-from-dec-to-bin)
- [Octave: refer to output like %10 in Mathematica?](https://superuser.com/questions/53045/octave-refer-to-output-like-10-in-mathematica)
- [How to do binary decimal calculations with bin2dec](https://superuser.com/questions/51419/octave-how-to-do-binary-calculations)

I suggest that we either migrate these to SO or burninate.  (I'd rather not do the latter as these are legitimate questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest we leave the questions that have been answered already (as in have an accepted and/or upvoted answers). There's no use in migrating them to SO.

I've migrated the recent question (2 months old) to SO, because it was new enough to get answered. But closed two of the other questions as off-topic that were too old.

For future reference, please flag these questions, because they are indeed on-topic for Stack Overflow and not really for Super User